# Confused About Integer and Char Type

Tags: java

There is a code like this :

```
boolean isValid(int ch) {
  if(ch < '1' | ch > '7' & ch != 'q') return false;
  else return true;
}


class HelpClassDemo {
...

  do {
    choice=(char) System.in.read();
  } while(!hlpobj.isValid(choice));
}
```

That's the question : 
Why we used `int ch` in `isValid(int ch)` in spite of choice's type is `char`?

Shouldn't we use `char ch` ? If we should use `int ch` why there is a code like this : `(ch < '1' | ch > '7' & ch != 'q')`

Isn't `ch<1` or `ch>7` logical ? I know it's a quite simple question but I'm confused about this.

Comment: See [The Java™ Tutorials - Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html): ***char:** The `char` data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of `'\u0000'` (or 0) and a maximum value of `'\uffff'` (or 65,535 inclusive).* It is a numeric type, supporting values between 0 and 65535 (inclusive), and will convert to `int` without needing cast, same as `short` will.

Comment: _Isn't `ch<1` or `ch>7` logical ?_ No, because then you're not comparing the ASCII (err.. Unicode) values, instead you are comparing integers.

Comment: *Unrelated:* The expression `ch < '1' | ch > '7' & ch != 'q'` actually means `ch < '1' | (ch > '7' & ch != 'q')`, which happens to work in your case, but you likely meant `(ch < '1' | ch > '7') & ch != 'q'`. In general, always use parenthesis when mixing `|` and `&`. --- Also, you should use `||` and `&&`, so it really should be `(ch < '1' || ch > '7') && ch != 'q'`. --- Personally, I'd have inverted it and simply written `return ((ch >= '1' && ch <= '7') || ch == 'q');`. Shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: I agree with OP, the method should use the more appropriate type `char`

Comment: @Andreas correctly used `return _logical expression_;` instead of the clumsier `if (_logical expression_) {return true;} else {return false;}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `int` type as a wider range than a `char` type (see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) data type range table). IMO, receiving a char as an int provides you with some kind of overflow protection (points of view on this are welcome) but it is not something I'd do as I'd use the right data type instead.

Now, when you compare

```
if(ch < '1' | ch > '7' & ch != 'q') return false;
```

you are implicitly casting '1' and '7' to int type, which is perfectly valid.

And finally, regarding

> Isn't ch<1 or ch>7 logical ? I know it's a quite simple question but
>   I'm confused about this.

It is logical, but it's not the same.

If you do `ch > '1' && ch < '7`', you are comparing ch to the `ASCII` value of 7, which is 55, and value of 1, which is 48. Basically, you are making sure that ch is a char between 2 and 6, both inclusive.

But if you do `ch > 1 && ch < 7`, you are comparing integers and validating that the char represented by ch is between 2 and 6 (both inclusive). This char is very likely to be not-human-readable.

If you want to make them equivalent, you wold have to compare according to the appropiate char value, like

```
if (ch > 48 && ch < 55)
```

Comment: when you do `ch < '1'` you are implicitly converting the `1` to an int not the other way around. `ch` remains an `int`

Comment: @LewBloch how is that more constructive than editing the answer and make it correct for every one that needs a correct answer on this?

Comment: @LewBloch Yes, you can, and you are encouraged to do it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120576/why-can-any-user-edit-any-other-users-question-or-answer

Comment: To clarify I meant `'1'` becomes 49 not `1`.